# No match for 'operator<' in 'std::operator.... What does this mean?

Tags: c++, operators

I am trying this very very simple operator overloading problem and i dont know what this error is. I

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>

using namespace std;

class Index
{
    public:
     int value;
    Index()
    {
      value=2;
    }
    int getInd()
    {
        return value;
    }
    void operator++()
    {
     value=value*2;
    }
}
int main()
{
    Index v;
    cout<<"v="<<v.getInd()<<endl;
    ++v;
    cout<<"v="<v.getInd();
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

This is the error: no match for 'operator<' in 'std::operator<< [with _Traits = std::char_traits](((std::basic_ostream >&)(&std::cout)), ((const char*)"v=")) < (&v)->Index::getInd()'

Why?? Its very annoying.

Comment: Seriosuly. When a compiler reports an error on a line, you should *read* and **re-read** that line closely *before* you ask about it. You would have noticed the `<` you used instead of `<<`.

Comment: Also, overloading the increment operator to multiply by 2 can be surprising for the uninitiated.

Comment: i am just trying something new. To see if that works as well..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means you've got a typo. It should be

```
cout<<"v="<<v.getInd();
```

the same as the line above.